# Head First C Program ( text search program)

Tags: c

I have a question regarding the below program from Head First C.
In the book under main function the writer did not used `search_for[strlen(search_for) - 1] = '\0';`; still his program ran fine. However when I used original version of the program (as per book),it was not able to find the text which I input. I got the below version from github(which can find text in string) but I still can't understand why it was used . If somebody can explain me I will really appreciate.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char tracks[][80] = {
    "I left my heart in Harvad Med School",
    "Newark, Newark -  Wonderful town",
    "Dancing with a Dork",
    "From here to maternity",
    "The girl from Iwo Jima",
};

void find_track(char search_for[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (strstr(tracks[i], search_for))
            printf("Track %i: '%s'\n", i, tracks[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char search_for[80];
    printf("Search for :");
    fgets(search_for, 80, stdin);
    search_for[strlen(search_for) - 1] = '\0';
    find_track(search_for);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 5, 80.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names,  then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: regarding: `for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)`  the 'magic' number 5 is the count of lines in the table `tracks[][80]`  1) it would be much better to declare the table as an array of pointers to char strings.  `char *table[] = ...`  then the `5` would be defined as: `sizeof( table ) / sizeof( table[0] )`

Comment: code should always check (!=NULL) the returned value from `fgets()` to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to cplusplus website, this line:

```
fgets(search_for, 80, stdin);
```

Is capturing the `newline` character, in the end of search_for.

If you type:

```
heart<intro>
```

You will get also the character representing the `intro` keystroke, and you won't find `heart\n` in the text.

So doing:

```
search_for[strlen(search_for) - 1] = '\0';
```

will *erase* the newline from the string (`heart\n` to `heart`), because if you do not strip the newline the search will fail.

> Reads characters from stream and stores them as a C string into str
>   until (num-1) characters have been read or either a newline or the
>   end-of-file is reached, whichever happens first.
>
> A newline character makes fgets stop reading, but it is considered a
>   valid character by the function and included in the string copied to
>   str.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just confirming So if I put 'heart' it was read like 'heart\n\0' due to fgets . We did removed it through search_for[strlen(search_for) - 1] = '\0'; I will appreciate if you can explain the syntax. I understood the logic not the syntax

Comment: You got it right, fgets gives you `heart\n\0`, you remove the `newline` character `\n`, that represents the `<intro>` or `<return>` key in your keyboard.

Comment: Yes because you do not put `heart` only, you put `heart<intro>`. If you do not press intro fgets does not read anything.

Answer (score -1):

```
search_for[strlen(search_for) - 1] = '\0';
```

'\0' is the explicit NULL terminator for string. A null-terminated string is a character string stored as an array containing the characters and terminated with a null character ('\0', called NUL in ASCII).

Comment: According to the standard yes, it does. `A terminating null character is automatically appended after the characters copied to str`.